# Copy Textbox Contents to Other Textbox

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I have a dynamically populated table as show in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNAF3/2/).  I have this piece of code, which will if a certain value is entered into one of textboxes in a particular class will change the other values to zero:

```
$(".SetOne").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 33) {
        $(".SetOne").not(this).val(0);
    }
});
```

How can I edit this code so that if the text in column 2 is "TOTAL_SET_OF_VALUES" and the value in column 7 is "3" that when a new value is entered in the textbox in column 8, this new value will be updated across the other textboxes in that class.

I would like to expand this code to account for on a row it is being used, if the text in column 2 equals "TOTAL_SET_OF_VALUES" and then the textbox in column 7 equals the value "3" or "3.0", that whatever value is placed in the textbox on that row - is then copied into the textboxes with the same classes.

**IF** text in col 2 = "TOTAL_SET_OF_VALUES"

**AND** value in textbox in col 7 = "3" or "3.0"

**THEN** whatever value is updated in the textbox in in col 8 is copied into the textbox in col 8 for the other textboses in the same class.

EDIT: Updated Fiddle link and added more detail.

Comment: your html code in jsfiddle is not valid:  some useless`</div>`

Comment: you need to be more clear in your explanation and fix up that fiddle.

Comment: Updated the original question a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some improvement that I made, question is not clear so I try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".SetOne").change(function() {
        var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var type = $tr.find("td:eq(1)").text().trim();
        var scale = $tr.find("td:eq(6) input").val();
        if(type == "TOTAL_SET_OF_VALUES" && (scale == 3 || scale == 3.0)) {
            $(".SetOne").not(this).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/FNAF3/5/)

Comment: is there any reason why this code isn't working in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: If you want that support, you shoud use 1.9.x

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things; your Fiddle wasn't running the `jQuery` because it wasn't queued - just add it in the *Frameworks & Extensions* section to the left. Wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() { })`, your `jQuery` will now run.

I believe I understood your question correctly; when the `TOTAL_SET_OF_VALUES` *Scale* is set to `3`, you want the monitor that row's *Source* and set the other fields with the same class to the new value `on.change()`.

Fiddle with my solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/UwZZk/).

Comment: Also, per @roasted's comment, cleaned up your `HTML` to be valid. Not sure where the extra `<div>` tags came from, but they shouldn't have been in there.

Comment: Hi @jterry that is fantastic.  Can I ask, how does `"#field_to_validate"` work?

Comment: I added the `field_to_validate` `ID` to the field we wanted to monitor (the _Scale_ of the `TOTAL_SET_OF_VALUES` row), and selected the element by that ID. Check out [jQuery's API reference](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) on selectors for a more in-depth dive :)